# How can I use an AppSetting from web.config in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-config

I have a web.config AppSetting value that I need to use it in my JS files. I use this code in my HTML file and I can't retrieve my variable in JS.

```
<script>
  var appSettingValue = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountsAuditMetricID"]';
  // '<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountsAuditMetricID"]%>';
  // The variable "appSettingValue" will contain the string from your web.config
</script>
```

I have this button in my page that I need to hide for some scenarios:

```
attributes: { 
  'class': 'k-grid-update', 
  'style': "#= metric_fk == $('#appSettingValue') ? 'display: none' : '' #" 
}
```

I need some help to see how can I use my web.config in my JS. Here is my config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="AccountsAuditMetricID" value="8"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Can you show us the rendered code that shows up in the browser? I'm not familiar with web.config, but I might be able to point you in the right direction if I can see the rendered html for the button and what shows up in the first script tag.

Comment: the button is creating with the command and this is using Kendo grid , the button is place into one of the grid cells, there is no html code for that...

Comment: {
                        command: {
                            text: "Update",
                            click: updateScore,

                        }, title: " ", width: "60", 
                        //attributes: { 'class': 'k-grid-update', 'style': "#= metric_nme == 'Account Audit' ? 'display: none' : '' #" }
                        attributes: { 'class': 'k-grid-update', 'style': "#= metric_fk == $('#appSettingValue') ? 'display: none' : '' #" }
                       

                    }

Comment: @omid, edit your question to add in that code, it's very hard to read as a comment.